# Error bs4: find_all | development vs production

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have no issues while running the below code in my development machine (localhost):

```
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36"}

exampleFile = requests.get(f'https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/petr4',headers=headers)
exampleSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(exampleFile.text, features="html.parser")
container_indicadores = exampleSoup.find('div', {'class': "indicator-today-container"}).find_all('div', {'title': True})
```

But, I've just pushed to Railway server (production) and now it rises the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

My goal is to grab all **divs** who have anything inside **title** and are inside the `div class="indicator-today-container"`

Info:

- python version is almost the same: production 3.10.8 | localhost: 3.10.1
- bs4 is in requirements as 4.11.1 - I'm assuming there is no difference between production and localhost
- Windows OS is in my localhost and I assume Linux is @ Railway server

Any idea?

EDIT:

I added 02 variables to find out the error:

```
example = exampleFile.text
first = exampleSoup.find('div', {'class': "indicator-today-container"})
```

Values:

```
 example = ('<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
 '<html lang="en-US">\n'
 '<head>\n'
 '    <title>Just a moment...</title>\n'
 '    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 
 charset=UTF-8">\n'
 '    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">\n'
 '    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">\n'
 '    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial- 
 scale=1">\n'
 '    <link href="/cdn-cgi/styles/challenges.css" 
 rel="stylesheet">\n'
 '    \n'
 '\n'
 '</head>\n'...)
```

But **first** variable is `None`

Comment: Have you printed out `exampleFile.text` to see what you get?  Perhaps the site blocks certain IPs.

Comment: @TimRoberts, I just edited the question to print out the error! It seems `example` variable is a string and has value but `first` variable is None type.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to grab all **divs** who have anything inside **title** and are inside the `div class="indicator-today-container"`

To avoid raising errors like this in these cases, it's better to avoid chaining `.find`s and instead use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php).

```py
container_indicadores = exampleSoup.select('div.indicator-today-container div[title]')
```

That way, even if you don't find anything, you'll end up with an empty list, but no errors will be raised.

---

> `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

> But **first** variable is `None`

[So the last line of your first snippet is basically equivalent to `container_indicadores = None.find_all('div', {'title': True})` and ofc that will raise an error.] You should check whether your request [was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#successful_responses)

```py
exampleFile = requests.get(f'https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/petr4',headers=headers)
print(exampleFile.status_code, exampleFile.reason, 'from', exampleFile.url)
```

For me, that prints ***`403 Forbidden from https://statusinvest.com.br/acoes/petr4`*** (and if I try with [cloudscraper](https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/) it raises a **`CloudflareChallengeError`** exception - *`Detected a Cloudflare version 2 Captcha challenge...`*, so they seem to have very good anti-bot blockers.)

---

> `example = exampleFile.text`

> Values:

Often, it's easier to spot the issue if you take a look at `exampleSoup.get_text()` instead:[image: cfErr]

---

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikUum.png) of what I get if I [use ScrapingAnt](https://pastebin.com/5ibz2F6p) [and I would expect similar results [with selenium](https://pastebin.com/VLZ2vPYK)].